# Maven in Azure DevOps can't find jar

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, maven-3

I'm using an Azure DevOps YAML build pipeline to compile some java code. The java code uses azure-storage-blob

## TL;DR

I can install a bunch of maven jar's but azure-storage-blob returns "Could not find artifact". I notice that it's path is `https://repo1.maven.org`, not `https://repo.maven.org`

## More details

Among other things I have this in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-security-keyvault-secrets</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
    <version>12.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

part of maven output looks like this:

```
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/microsoft/azure/azure-keyvault-core/1.0.0/azure-keyvault-core-1.0.0.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-nop/1.7.21/slf4j-nop-1.7.21.jar (4.0 kB at 660 B/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/20.0/guava-20.0.jar (2.4 MB at 399 kB/s)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:53 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-11-26T12:22:10Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project XYZ: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.function:Decryption_POC_JAVA:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.azure:azure-storage-blob:jar:12.4.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
The process '/usr/bin/mvn' failed with exit code 1
Could not retrieve code analysis results - Maven run failed.
```

So it can successfully download a whole bunch of jars from
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/microsoft/azure/

But it can't download just the blob jar in particular

What I have discovered is that this file *doesn't* exist:

https://repo.maven.org/maven2/com/azure/azure-storage-blob/12.14.0/azure-storage-blob-12.14.0.jar

(I *assume* this is where it's looking, but I can't get it to display it)

However this file does:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/azure/azure-storage-blob/12.14.0/azure-storage-blob-12.14.0.jar

Note this is *repo1* not *repo*. I only found this because [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-storage-blob/12.14.0) Maven page specified it.

So I tried to force to look at repo1 by adding this to pom.xml

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central1</id>
      <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

The error changes to

> Failed to collect
> dependencies at com.azure:azure-storage-blob:jar:12.4.0: Failed to
> read artifact descriptor for com.azure:azure-storage-blob:jar:12.4.0:
> Could not transfer artifact com.azure:azure-storage-blob:pom:12.4.0
> from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror
> for repositories: [central1 (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2, default

My questions are:

1. Can I get maven to display the URL it's downloading from?
2. Why would this file be at repo1 and not repo (the other files are at repo and not repo1)
3. If maven is so awesome why is this dumb thing happening and how can I fix it

Note that I'm using Azure DevOps and I don't have a lot of maven experience so I'm not sure if I can clear caches or clear local maven repos or anything like that. Also this an existing setup that I'm trying to get working.

Here's the parts of the YAML that matter:

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
      - "src/*"
      - "pom.xml"

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs: 
    - job: mavenBuild
      pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
      steps:
        - task: Maven@3
          inputs:
            mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
            mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
            javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
            jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
            jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
            publishJUnitResults: true
            testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
            goals: 'package'
```

Comment: In the end I just removed the artifact to get it to run through and it actually appeared to build OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this issue in Azure Pipeline `Could not find artifact com.azure:azure-storage-blob:jar:12.4.0` too.

I found something interesting from this [maven link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-storage-blob/12.4.0) that is `Jar (474KB)` link has broken. So I changed `com.azure:azure-storage-blob:jar` version to the latest version `12.14.2`.

it's work. Azure Pipelines can download this artifact from Maven Central Repo.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. I also suspected it was something broken in Maven. It's kind of ridiculous that the whole purpose of Maven is to deliver packages but then it has broken links.